# Ignoring Strings raised using pandas "where"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm wondering if where's a way to skip the strings from when I re-tag the values from number to string:

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(1,100,1))
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the 1st and 2nd Standard deviation from my sample data:

```
s = s.where((s <= s.std() *1) & (s >= s.std() *-1), "1_StDev", errors="ignore")
s = s.where((s <= s.std() *2) & (s >= s.std() *-2), "2_StDev", errors="ignore")
```

But it seems that my code is still returning an error despite of setting the error parameter to `"ignore"`.

Also, I am wondering if `pd.cut` is feasible here. If so, please teach me how.

Comment: The error is not from `where`. After excuting the firstline, there's `int`s and `"1_StDev"` in `s`, which you uses to get a new `std` in the second line.

Comment: @Chris, you're correct so setting `errors="ignore"` in where will not have the where method ignore the string? also, I tried adding `s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,int))` in the mix but it didn't helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```py
conditions = [(s <= s.std() *1) & (s >= s.std() *-1), 
              (s <= s.std() *2) & (s >= s.std() *-2)]
choices = ["1_StDev", "2_StDev"]

s = pd.Series(np.select(conditions, choices))
```

Better to set default as @Chris suggest for values where conditions do not match.

```py
s = pd.Series(np.select(conditions, choices, default=s))
```

Comment: Good answer; but I would add `default=s` to `numpy.select` so rows that didn't meet the conditions are still intact ;)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you call the second line you've already converted part of the Series to string and therefore there is an error when you compare the string to a float.